# How can use puppeteer with my current chrome (keeping my credentials)

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

i'm actually trying to use puppeteer for scraping and i need to use my current chrome to keep all my credentials and use it instead of relogin and type password each time which is a really time lose !

is there a way to connect it ? how to do that ?
i'm actually using node v11.1.0
and puppeteer 1.10.0

```
let scrape = async () => {
const browser = await log()
const page = await browser.newPage()           
const delayScroll = 200
// Login 
await page.goto('somesite.com');
await page.type('#login-email', '*******);
await page.type('#login-password', "******");
await page.click('#login-submit');
// Wait to login
await page.waitFor(1000);
```

}

and now it will be perfect if i do not need to use that and go on page (headless, i dont wan't to see the page opening i'm just using the info scraping in node) but with my current chrome who does not need to login to have information i need. (because at the end i want to use it as an extension of chrome)

thx in advance if someone knows how to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First welcome to the community.

You can use Chrome instead of Chromium but sincerely in my case, I get a lot of errors and cause a mess with my personal tabs. So you can create and save a profile, then you can login with a current or a new account.

In your code you have a function called "log" I'm guessing that there you set launch puppeeteer.

```
const browser = await log()
```

Into that function use arguments and create a relative directory for your profile data:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ["--user-data-dir=./Google/Chrome/User Data/"]
});
```

Run your application, login with an account and the next time you enter you should see your credentials

Any doubt please add a comment.

Comment: hello i tried your method and ano other one ===> 
           ``` const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false, 
            executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome',
        // userDataDir:'/Users/lucasteisseire/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1'
    });```
and does not work cant launch google browser chrome with my puppeteer using my profile

Comment: You cant do both things? I noticed a missing "dot" before your paths:executablePath: './Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'

Comment: Sometimes you can have permission issues, so tried to copy your profile folder into your puppeteer project folder.